# How to bundle a core file with its associated executables?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, coredump

How can I bundle a core file with its associated executables and shared libraries?

When a program crashes, it generates a core file, that I can use to debug it with gdb. But if someone comes along behind me and "helpfully" recompiles the program with extra debugging turned on, or upgrades a package, or in any way messes with the system, that core file becomes useless.

So what I'd like is a way to bundle the core dump file with all of the other binaries that it references, into one big file.

Then, of course, I also need a way to open this file in gdb. I don't want to have to "extract" the files back to their original location and overwrite upgraded or changed binaries. I'm imagining a shell script that extracts the binaries to a temp directory and then tells gdb to look there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gdb already has the information that you wanted (`info sharedlib`):

```
$ gdb -ex 'set height 0' -ex 'set confirm off' \
  -ex 'file /path/to/exe' -ex 'core-file core.pid' \
  -ex 'info sharedlib' -ex quit
```

So naturally you can ask gdb to give you this list, and from there you can create a "gdb-bundle" tarball that contains the executable and all the shared libraries that gdb reported.

I wrote a script to automate this:

```
#!/bin/sh
me=$(basename $0)

usage() {
    echo "Usage:
  $me -p <pid>
  $me <executable> <core>

DESCRIPTION
  $me - Creates a tarball containing the executable, it's core dump and
        all the shared libraries that gdb said it loads.

OPTIONS
    -p <pid>  A running process id of a process to be bundled.
    -h        Show this help message"
}

pid=
while getopts hp: opt
do
    case "$opt" in
        p)
            pid="$OPTARG"
            ;;
        h)
            usage
            exit
            ;;
        \?)
            echo Unknown option
            exit
            ;;
    esac
done
shift $(($OPTIND -1))
executable=$1
corename=$2

if [ -n "$pid" ]; then
    test "$pid" -gt 0 || { echo "pid must be numeric"; exit 1; }
    proc=/proc/$pid/exe
    executable=`readlink -e $proc` ||
        { echo "Could not readlink $proc"; exit 1; }
    corename=${basename}.$pid.core
else
    test -z "$executable" && usage && exit 1;
    test -z "$corename" && usage && exit 1;
fi

basename=$(basename $executable)
if [ -n "$pid" ]; then
    sharedlibs=$(gdb -ex "attach $pid" -ex 'set height 0' \
        -ex 'set confirm off' -ex "generate-core-file $corename" \
        -ex 'info sharedlib' -ex quit|
        sed -n '/Shared Object Library/,/^(/p'|grep -E '(Yes|No)'|
        sed -e 's,[^/]\+,,') || exit 1
    dir="gdb-${basename}.$pid.$(date +%F-%H%M%S)"
else
    sharedlibs=$(gdb -ex 'set height 0' -ex 'set confirm off' \
        -ex "file $executable" -ex "core-file $corename" \
        -ex 'info sharedlib' -ex quit|
        sed -n '/Shared Object Library/,/^(/p'|grep -E '(Yes|No)'|
        sed -e 's,[^/]\+,,') || exit 1
    dir="gdb-${basename}.$(date +%F-%H%M%S)"
fi

mkdir "$dir" && cp "$corename" "$dir" &&
tar chf - $sharedlibs $executable|tar -C $dir -xf - &&
echo -e "gdb:\n\tgdb -ex 'set solib-absolute-prefix ./'" \
    "-ex 'file .$executable' -ex 'core-file ./$corename' " \
    > $dir/makefile &&
echo tar czf $dir.tar.gz $dir &&
tar czf $dir.tar.gz $dir
```

Answer (score 0):

You could trap SIGSEGV and then write a subprocess to copy the related process files (using lsof) into a temp directory.

Answer (score 0):

First find the binary associated with the core. You have a few options:

1. Configure the system to name cores after the binary the caused them, and have your binaries be installed in a standard location your script can grab them from. Instructions for naming the cores [are here](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/Tips%20and%20Tricks/coredump.htm?ref=news.rdf), also see core(5).
2. If you can't configure the system, the best I've come up with is running strings on the core, and then for each string that's a valid path running "file" on it and grepping for "ELF" and "executable". This can get the you the wrong answer, in particular if the binary was invoked by another utility (like make) they might appear in the core, so you can add additional filters like excluding paths inside /bin and /usr/bin if you know your binaries are always in say /opt, and picking the binary that has the most recent mtime (newer software is more likely to be coring and more likely to be yours rather than software that shipped with the system).
3. A supplemental trick is to look for "_=/your/binary/here" in the strings output -- "_" is a special environment variable set by some shells/WMs/apps to the binary they're invoking. It can also be misleading though (e.g. it will be /usr/bin/make when make invoked your binary).

Second, gather the dependencies for the binary:

1. Grep the strings output from the core again for values of LD_PRELOAD and LD_LIBRARY_PATH. These can affect what libraries the binary actually linked.
2. Run "ldd" on the binary, with those variables set to the same values, and split on "=>" to find the filenames of each of the libraries.

Then copy it all into a directory and run tar on it. Copying log files into the directory is often also helpful.